# Как поставить скрипт битрикса на cron?

Tags: php, битрикс

Как поставить битриксовский скрипт на крон? А именно, хочу чтобы генерация sitemap, запускалась каждый день в 11 утра. Сейчас в файле /etc/crontab прописал:

```
00 11 * * *  bitrix test -f /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/seo/admin/sitemap_cron.php && { /usr/bin/php -f /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/seo/admin/sitemap_cron.php ; } >/dev/null 2>&1
```

и скопировал файл seo_sitemap_run.php в sitemap_cron.php и добавил в файле:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = "/home/bitrix/www";
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

define("NO_KEEP_STATISTIC", true);
define("NOT_CHECK_PERMISSIONS", true);

require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules­/main/include/prolog_before.php");
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: И что не работает?

Comment: Скрипт не запускается